# Need Drawable filepath for Instrumentation Testing Android

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way to get the filepath for a file in the drawable folder for instrumentation testing.

I have a Bitmap class that requires a filepath to decode and scale the image.  The image is stored in `res/drawable`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find a way to get the filepath for a file in the drawable folder for instrumentation testing

There is no "filepath", because resources are not files on the device. They are files on your development machine, and they are entries in the APK file on the device.

> I have a Bitmap class that requires a filepath to decode and scale the image

Then you need to improve upon that `Bitmap` class to support other data sources. Or, you need to implement your tests in a way that uses actual files, not resources.